# index.js not doing what index.ts does

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, systemjs

I'm currently building a webapp with angular2 and typescript. I tried to use `index.ts` so in my code, I could simply use

```
import {LayoutComponent} from '../layout';
```

But when I transpile, the javascript engine won't look for `index.js` but for `./layout` so it doesn't work.

Is there a config for the typescript transpiler, something I should configure with systemjs or use another loader like webpack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the cause of this. Typescript is using nodejs module resolution explained here :
http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

But systemjs does not use nodejs resolution. So I need to use `./layout/index` to be compatible with systemjs module resolution or use a map entry for every modules. But commonjs does use nodejs resolution so I'm gonna transpile to commonjs and use webpack.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the **systemjs** needs to be configured :

You should have something like this in your index.html file :

```
  System.config({
    packages: {
      src: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
    System.import('src/dist/boot') --- your path to root file
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

On Angular2 docs page you can find a [five minutes quick start tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart), follow that one and after that, you can customize your app how you want: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: I already have followed the quickstart and my index.html contains exactly the same code. My app works find if I use the `'../layout/index'` But I want to be able to use the full power of `index.ts` by simply using `'../layout'`